# Change background image of clicked UIButton created programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I have created `UIButtons` programatically and added them to my `UIScrollView`.Now I want to change the background image of clicked `UIButton` to an image and others should remain in blue color which is the default color.Now when I click another `UIButton`, I want to change the previously clicked `UIButton` to blue and currently clicked button to have the bg image.

This is the code for creating and setting `UIButton` properties:

```
   for (int i=0; i<[arrPartVenuDetails count]; i++) {

        NSString *venueId = [[arrPartVenuDetails objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"venue_id"];
        NSInteger venue_id= [venueId integerValue];
        NSLog(@"venue id %ld",(long)venue_id);

        aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 20.f)];

        [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(6/255.0) green:(130/255.0) blue:(195/255.0) alpha:1]];
        NSString *buttonClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"VENUE %d", i+1];
        [aButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];

        [aButton setTitle:buttonClassName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight );
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(venueButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        aButton.tag = venue_id;
        [scrollVenue addSubview:aButton];

        yCoord += buttonHeight + buffer;
    }
```

This is button click method:

```
-(void) venueButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender{

    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"venue .png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    CGRect btnOnclickFrame = sender.frame;
    btnOnclickFrame.size.width = 210;
    sender.frame = btnOnclickFrame;
 }
```

Comment: on click event of button, check its tag. if its first button, then set its background color to red and all others to default blue. like this you can do for all other buttons.

Comment: You are already setting tags to the buttons. What good are they if you don't use them? (Though as a matter of fact I learnt it the hard way that tags are not good at all)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `venueButtonClick` as follows:

```
-(void) venueButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender{
     for (UIButton *btn in scrollVenue) {

        if (btn.tag==sender.tag) {

            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"venue .png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else{

            [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(6/255.0) green:(130/255.0) blue:(195/255.0) alpha:1]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I replace `for (UIButton *btn in scrollVenue) ` with `for (UIButton *aButton) `?

Comment: yes, you can give any name and add this for loop in venueButtonClick method.

Comment: What a horrible way to use loops!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property to your `.h` file.

```
@property NSUInteger lastSelectedTag;
```

In your `viewDidLoad`, assign it some safe value:

```
_lastSelectedTag = 80807652;//example value as it will be unique
```

Now in your `IBAction`, change it like this:

```
-(void) venueButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender{

    if(_lastSelectedTag!=80807652)
    {
        //lastSelectedTag is different than our safe value so it means that it now contains tag of real last selected button
        UIButton *lastSelectedButton = [scrollVenue viewWithTag:_lastSelectedTag]; //This is the previously selected button

        //Change it to blue and do whatever you want
       [lastSelectedButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];//remove background image
       [lastSelectedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(6/255.0) green:(130/255.0) blue:(195/255.0) alpha:1]]; //give it color

    }
   [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"venue .png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    CGRect btnOnclickFrame = sender.frame;
    [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    btnOnclickFrame.size.width = 210;
    sender.frame = btnOnclickFrame;
    _lastSelectedTag = sender.tag; //Set lastSelectedButton to this button's tag
}
```

By the way, a suggestion, you will be better off using `UITableView` instead of `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other possibilities:

1. If your creating 3-4 button you might be better using `UISegmentedControl` which will allow you to customise it and save you having to write all that extra code.

[image]

[See the apple docs for details on how to customise](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISegmentedControl)

2. If your creating many buttons then a `UITableView` might be more suitable, and use the selected property of the `UITableViewCell`, you will need to create a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uh no. He is creating unlimited number of buttons based on count of an array. While it is true that using scrollView is not right in that scenario, your suggestion however is not correct. UITableView is what is needed

Comment: Let's say there are going to be 15 buttons. How will you fit those in iPhone width segmented control?